# TortoiseSVN client-side hooks in project properties (delete cache files)

Tags: windows, svn, cmd, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

I have several `php`-projects under SVN control. I want to delete compiled php-template files after update on the client side;  these files are located in `./tmp/smarty/compile` folder. So using windows command line I can do this using

```
del /Q path_to_my_project\tmp\smarty\compile
```

If I run this command in cmd.exe all files are successfully deleted.

using projects properties `tsvn:postupdatehook` I should use `%REPOROOT%` placeholder for project path. so my command becomes:

```
del /Q %REPOROOT%\tmp\smarty\compile
```

`del` is the `cmd.exe` command, so I need to run `cmd.exe` first and then run desired command. so finally my hook command looks like:

```
cmd.exe /c del /Q %REPOROOT%\tmp\smarty\compile
```

when I run this using `Win+R` (with `reporoot` changed to full path) it works fine too.

Then I put this line to SVN properties (I should replace `\` slashes to `/`, overwise SNV returns `http`-path to repository, not local path), and try to update project. TortoiseSVN asks me if I want to run hook:

```
cmd.exe /c  del /Q D:\_projects\webCakePHP\.....\tmp\smarty\compile
```

So here `reporoot` is successfully translated to correct working copy path.
Everything looks fine, but when I run this hook, it successfully deletes files in `tmp\smarty\compile` but **it also deletes all files from working copy dir**.

the question is, what am I doing wrong, and how to delete files after update right way.

I've tried to put quotes some ways but it doesn't delete enything at all or says that there is no such directory.

thanks

Comment: Perhaps it helps putting quotation marks around the path: `del /Q "%REPOROOT%\tmp\smarty\compile"`; otherwise, in case spaces or other token separators occur, `del` interprets it as multiple paths unexpectedly...

Comment: @aschipfl there are no spaces in path, but with such quotes it does nothing, as I remember. I tried to quote path and whole del command and double quote del-path with escaping :(

Comment: Quoting paths does never harm, it just avoids trouble with whitespaces and avoids the need of escaping special characters...

Answer (score 0):

as an alternate solution to my question, i've created `.bat` file in `%REPOROOT%/bin` folder, which deletes files:

```
pushd %~dp0..\tmp\smarty\compile
del /Q *
popd
```

and my hook cmd string is `%REPOROOT%/bin/clearCache.bat`.

this is not exact answer to my question because it requires `bat`-file creation and isn't one-line hook.